# how to show two api value in one column widget inside text widget and checkbox widget

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I have two api where first api has title and second api value is boolean value false or true. I want to show both data inside a column where
ListTile(
leading: Text(title here), //first Api value
trailing: CheckBox(value: apiValue, onChanged(newVal){})) //second api value

Comment: Can u describe more or can show example of apis response?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FutureBuilder widget. In your case since there are two API endpoints, I suggest you set the 'future' parameter to something like

```
Future.wait([getTitleFromApiOne(), getBooleanFromApiTwo()])
```

You can then access this data in your ListView builder

```
var title = snapshot.data[0][index].title // Data from API call 1
var isCheckboxMarked = snapshot.data[1].value // Data from API call 2
```

Now you can use it in your ListTile widget

```
ListTile( leading: Text(title), //first Api value trailing: 
CheckBox(value: isCheckboxMarked, onChanged(newVal){})) //second api value
```